# What do the labels in this documentation mean?

Tags: texas-instruments

I am looking on page 9 of the [TI CC8520 Documentation](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc8520.pdf) and I see that there are some capacitors and inductors around the antenna with labels such as C306.  What does that mean?  How can I know the values of these components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below links, It might help you it consists of Schematic,BOM etc

[CC85XX-CC2590EM 1.1.0 Hardware Reference Design (Rev. A)](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=swrc185&fileType=zip)

[CC85XXEM_2.1 Hardware Reference Design (Rev. B)](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=swrc080&fileType=zip)

Answer (score 1):

Those labels are called "reference designators"  By themselves they don't tell you anything about the components, but they do provide a link between the component shown on the schematic, an entry in the Bill of Materials (BOM) or parts list, and the actual component on the PC board.

I expect that those schematics are taken from Family User Guide or other documents available from TI.  Those other documents should have the BOM which will give the part values and other details.

Comment: Thanks! I just checked out the CC85xx Family User Guide and don't see it in there.  From what I'm seeing [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/swra297), it looks like the design was made by another company, Johanson Technology, but I haven't found the values anywhere yet.